# Count the number of matches for a prefix in a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in an SQL server that looks like the one below and I want to count the number of unique occurrences where specific prefixes are used in the data column, like "21:00:00".

Dataset:

```
+-------------------------+
|          data           |
+-------------------------+
| 21:00:00:24:ff:5e:3a:bd |
| 50:01:43:80:18:6b:2a:4c |
| 21:00:00:1b:32:0f:a7:54 |
| 10:00:00:90:fa:a8:da:2a |
+-------------------------+
```

Desired query output:

```
+----------+----------+----------+
| 21:00:00 | 50:01:43 | 10:00:00 |
+----------+----------+----------+
|        2 |        1 |        1 |
+----------+----------+----------+
```

I have been able to get the query to count a single prefix at a time by using this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT wwpn) AS "21:00:00" FROM table WHERE wwpn LIKE '21:00:00%'
```

However, I want to count multiple prefixes as shown in the desired query output.

Comment: ...is this SQL Server? Oracle? DB2? the world may never know.

Comment: This is SQL Server.

Comment: @lollan Have you tried anything?  If so please edit your own question and put it in the original question.

Comment: Is the prefix always defined as ##:##:## so 8 characters?  use LEFT (data,8) , to do the PIVOT part if you don't know the prefixes ahead of time you will have to use dynamic pivot

Answer (score 2):

I've been waiting for someone to do a dynamic pivot (like Matt said in the comments) but no one has done it yet : (...I tried it myself and this is what I managed...

`Query`:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + LEFT(QUOTENAME(data), 9) + ']' 
        FROM DataTable
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

set @query = N'SELECT ' + @cols + N' from 
         (
            select LEFT(data, 8) as data, COUNT(*) as count
            from DataTable
            GROUP BY LEFT(data, 8)
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            max(count)
            for data in (' + @cols + N')
        ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

`Results:`

```
10:00:00 | 21:00:00 | 50:01:43
---------|----------|---------
    1    |    2     |    1
---------|----------|---------
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this query:

```
SELECT LEFT([Data], 8) as prefix, count(*) as cnt
    FROM tableName
    GROUP BY LEFT([Data], 8);
```

Comment: This is going to give the answer in rows rather than columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the prefixes in advance then you can do something simple like this;

Create test data;

```
CREATE TABLE #TestData (FieldName nvarchar(50))
INSERT INTO #TestData
VALUES
 ('21:00:00:24:ff:5e:3a:bd')
,('50:01:43:80:18:6b:2a:4c')
,('21:00:00:1b:32:0f:a7:54')
,('10:00:00:90:fa:a8:da:2a')
```

Query

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN FieldName LIKE '21:00:00%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [21:00:00]
,SUM(CASE WHEN FieldName LIKE '50:01:43%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [50:01:43]
,SUM(CASE WHEN FieldName LIKE '10:00:00%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [10:00:00]
FROM #TestData
```

Result

```
21:00:00    50:01:43    10:00:00
2           1           1
```